# probability elevator problem revisit

Tags: probability

just want to make sure I have this right. This is different version.

An elevator starts with five passengers and stops at six floors, starting from the first floor.

What is the probability that the elevator has no one inside after the second floor?

Here's what I have
There are 6 possible ways for this to happen. It can have 5 people get out on the first floor, 4 people 1st floor 1 people 2nd floor, and so on. there is only 1 way to arrange 5 people getting out or zero people getting out on the first floor. But there are different combination for 4 people, 3 people, 2 people and 1 people getting out of the first floor.

So the probability should be

(5C0 + 5C1 + 5C2 + 5C3 +5C4 + 5C5) / 6^5

Am I right??

Thanks

Comment: Can someone give a comment???? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

So you are wondering what the odds are that all 5 people get off the elevator on floor one or floor two out of six floors. So (2/6)^5 or about .412%